# subtracting mean of each column away from the column and returning it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with many columns. I have to create a function which gets the mean of each column and subtracts it from each row in the column and then returns that dataset with those means subtracted. I found a similar question asked here and applied the answer but i keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
def exercise1(df):
    df1 = DataFrame(df)
    df2 = df1 - df1.mean()
    return df2

exercise1(data)

# Where data is the a csv file regarding salaries in the San Francisco area.
```

I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: `<U32` appears to be string. Does your data contain string values? If so, you obviously can't take mean of those.

Comment: @Quang Hoang Yes, there is one column with the name of each person. All other columns are numerical. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a for loop on column with `try-except`:

```
def exercise1(df):
    df1 = df.copy()
    for col in df1.columns:
        try:     # if we can compute the mean then substract
            df1[col] -= df1[col].mean()
        except:  # otherwise just ignore the column
            pass

    return df1
```

Answer (score 1):

df.mean() produces a pandas Series data type with only numerical columns from your original DataFrame.

```
means = df.mean()
```

You can get the index values of that series by using:

```
means.index
```

Use this to slice your original DataFrame and subtract the mean value

```
df2 = df[means.index] - means
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column you're subtracting from:

```
df = {'values1': [1,2,3], 'values2': [4,5,6]}
def exercise1(df):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df2 = df1['values2'] - df1['values2'].mean()
    return df2

print(exercise1(df))
```